# Android Studio: How can I put image at the bottom of actionbar?

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm using recyclerview that loops the images but it starts behind the actionbar as shown below. I wanted the image to appear starting below of the action bar. I tried using the android layout below but still doesn't. Any solution guys? Thanks !!!!

[image: Image of the application]

## Activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB1"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>






</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## Content_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
    style="@style/RippleStyleWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/black_bg" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_overlay"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_android"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Title"
                android:gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding margin top to the RecyclerView ?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```